# Virtualbox problems on Windows emulation

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox, fedora

I've been experiencing a problem with Virtualbox on my Fedora 13. 
When I try to setup virtual machine instance with Windows it just hangs the system with no reaction on keyboard commands with no respond to anything except physical halting. Please help what might be the problem?

Sultan

Comment: this post belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of the virtualbox are you using, is the latest. Also you could try to re-install the software it may help you. One thing that usually helps is to delete the disk image file that you create for the image or use a different iso file to install your windows iamge.

Try one of those solutions, can't say what is the specific problem with your description

regards